# Array declared within main throws stack overflow, declared outside main does not

Tags: c++

I have the below code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int pnp[2][105],fin[2][105];
    int time[105],n,m,dummy,prod = 0;
    int const maxvv = 2000000;
    int d[maxvv];
    return 0;
}
```

I get a stackoverflow at `int d[maxvv]`. However, if I shift to the global scope

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int const maxvv = 2000000;
int d[maxvv];
int main(){
    int pnp[2][105],fin[2][105];
    int time[105],n,m,dummy,prod = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

I do not get this error. Can anybody tell me what is the difference. Using vs 2008 with c++ on windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're ruining the stack. It's usually around ~1MB in size and you're allocating more than that. Moving to global space resolves your error, because there is much more space available there than in stack.

Comment: Wait. So if you declare an array within main, it is allocated memory in the stack? Where is it stored if it is declared globally?

Comment: Yes.  All local variables are allocated in the stack.

Comment: @Programmer If you declare it globally, it's generally stored in the data segment of the executable.

Comment: how large is the data segment of the executable?